When does the Magnus Expansion converge for integrating angular velocity?
Because three-dimensional rotations about different axes do not commute, the angular velocity vector is not equal to the derivative of the angular displacement vector with respect to time.  Instead they’re related by the following formula, involving the Jacobian of $SO(3)$:
$$ \vec{\omega}=  \dot{\vec{\theta}} - \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta^2} \left(\vec{\theta} \times \dot{\vec{\theta}}\right) + \frac{\theta - \sin \theta}{\theta^3} \left(\vec{\theta} \times \left(\vec{\theta} \times \dot{\vec{\theta}}\right)\right)\,  $$
Finding the angular displacement vector in terms of the angular velocity vector is even more complicated.  The rotation matrix satisfies the matrix differential equation $R’(t) = O(t) R(t)$ where $O(t)$ is the skew-symmetric matrix corresponding to the angular velocity.  Its solution $R(t) = exp(\vec{\theta}(t))$ can be found using the Magnus expansion, which in the case of constant angular acceleration works out to $$\vec{\theta}(t) = \vec{\omega_0} t + \frac{1}{2} \vec{\alpha} t^2 + \frac{1}{12} \vec{\alpha}\times \vec{\omega_0} t^3 +\frac{1}{240} \vec{\alpha}\times(\vec{\alpha}\times \vec{\omega_0})t^5 + …$$
My question is, what is the radius of convergence of this Magnus expansion? This blog post asserts that it converges when the angle of rotation is less than $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$.  Is that correct, and if so why?

I think that your question can better answered  in  [math.se] portal ?

what is $\vec\alpha$?

The wiki you linked also lists a criterion for convergence; despite our best effort, we cannot yet prove a bigger convergence radius. I'm not sure what it is you want to ask of it?

@ZeroTheHero Angular acceleration.

@naturallyInconsistent Wikipedia describes convergence in terms of a matrix norm.  What does the matrix norm of the skew symmetric matrix corresponding to the angular velocity vector equal?

Something that you can calculate. And then lament at how small the provable convergence radius is. It actually works for a range far wider, but we don't know how to improve the proof.

@naturallyInconsistent If you post an answer doing the calculation and noting the fact that the actual radius of convergence is larger but unknown, I’d be happy to accept it.

@naturallyInconsistent Are you going to post an answer?  There’s a bounty on it now.  By the way, how do we know that the range is wider than the matrix norm range?

@KeshavSrinivasan the 2-norm of your skew-symmetric angular velocity matrix, and hence the integral, will depend on the specific form of that matrix. The 2-norm of the matrix is its largest singular value.

@MartinC. OK, so given that we’re talking about the angular velocity vector derived from constant angular acceleration, so omega_0 + alpha t, what is the largest singular value of the skew-symmetric matrix corresponding to the angular velocity vector?  And is naturallyinconsistent right that this Magnus expansion has a bigger radius of convergence than what is indicated by the matrix norm?
